# Accessing / Setting global settings of the iOS-Settings-App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ipod-touch

Is there any possibility to programmatically access/change the (global) settings, the one accessible via the Settings-Icon on every iDevice.

Background: I want to do some changes to the localization settings inside my app. (And no, I'm not planning on releasing it to the App Store => yes, it can use private API ;) )

Comment: If you are interested in undocumented API's I would consider committing to the [`Jailbreak Proposal`](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18154/ios-jailbreaking-development?referrer=v3HFF-ebzgSz6aewN1cCiQ2). Sometimes it is difficult to get answers about undocumented API's here.

Comment: I'm not so sure. I don't want a jailbreak and I most certainly won't advise my customer to jailbreak his devices :O

Comment: It is called iOS Jailbreaking Development but is also about using undocumented API's without Jailbreaking (the name is somewhat of a deterrent I know).

Comment: Without jailbreak this won't be possible, since the apps are sandboxed.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to change. You can set region format of your app using setLocale function of the dateFormatter, you can set date format as 24 or 12 hour format in your app, regardless of the time format set in your device using setDateFormat etc. You cannot change the setting in the phone but you can make your app to follow the settings that you want.